# Is there a way to use the sheet name from a certain cell (which has been populated using that sheet) to populate another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Let me try to be more clear:

[Here's an image that illustrates what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msXFq.png)

Essentially, my goal would be to have a formula that I could put into cell A2 (or a macro, if necessary) that would insert the name of the sheet that cell B2 comes from. In this case, that would be Sheet2. I've tried a bit through the macro recorder, but I haven't been able to get anything to work the way I want it to.

Ideally, I'd be able to select a cell (in this case, cell A2) and activate a macro or put in a formula that would populate that cell (A2) with the Sheet that the cell to the right of it (B2) comes from.

Thanks a ton for your help, any guidance as to what I should use for this or how I could do this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Can the formula be more complex than that, or will it always be a single-cell link ?  Could it point to a cell in a different workbook?

Comment: The data I have right now, while there's a **lot** of it, doesn't get a lot more complex than that. I really just need a way to convert the 'source' sheet of a nearby cell to the text displayed by the selected cell, if that makes sense.

Comment: What I'm trying right now is converting the formula to text and then cutting off the beginning and end of that string to get the sheet name. However, that doesn't work as I'd like it to due to the fact that the formulae for the cells which have the string name sometimes have different amounts of characters at the beginning and end due to some references being over 10 and some under 10, as well as some cells having - signs at the beginning of their formulae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a UDF that will pull the sheet name for a simple `=SheetX!RANGE` formula. It will also alert if there are multiple sheet references or none at all.

Place this in a standard module and in a cell type `=ReturnSheet(B2)`

```
Function ReturnSheet(rng As Range) As String

    Dim sFormula As String
    sFormula = rng.Formula

    If InStr(1, sFormula, "!") = 0 Then

        Dim sSheet As String
        sSheet = "No sheet precedents found!"

    Else

       If UBound(Split(sFormula, "!")) = 1 Then


            sSheet = Mid(sFormula, 2, InStr(1, sFormula, "!") - 2)

        Else

            sSheet = "Multiple Sheet precendents!"

        End If

    End If

    ReturnSheet = Replace(sSheet,"'","") 'replace single quote in sheet names that has spaces

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works perfectly, really helpful.

Comment: Sheet names with spaces will be wrapped in single quotes, so you may need to adjust for that.